# Marginpars inside tcolorboxes

Tags: tcolorbox, marginpar

Is there some combination of packages that allows us to get `marginpar` to work inside a `tcolorbox` environment?

Answer (score 1):

A margin note inside a tcolorbox is an issue because `\marginpar` internally is a float, so you cannot place it nested into another floats, nor into non float boxes, as a minipage, a footnote or a `\parbox`, producing in these cases a "Float(s) lost" error. In tcolorbox is the same issue. But you can:

1. Attach the margin note before of after the tcolorbox, and then adjust the vertical position as needed. With `marginnotes` and `sidenotes`packages you can include an offset as optional parameter, and therefore is a bit simpler.
2. If floating behaviour is turned on in tcolorbox, it could end far away of an attached margin note, but you can use `before` and `after` options of the tcolorbox, and then the note will make the same trip that the box. Note that you will need compile more than once to see that nots in the correct place.

Example:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum,parskip}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-2]

\marginnote{Margin note 1}[2\baselineskip]
\begin{tcolorbox}[after={\marginpar{\vspace{-2\baselineskip}Inside note 1}}] 
\lipsum[3][1-6] 
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[after={\sidenotetext[4][-3\baselineskip]{Side note }}] 
\lipsum[3][1]\sidenotemark[4] \lipsum[3][3-6] 
\end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum[4][1-3]

\marginnote{Margin note 2}[2\baselineskip]
\begin{tcolorbox}[float,floatplacement=b, before float={\marginnote{Inside note 2}[\baselineskip]}] 
    \lipsum[3][1-5] 
\end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum[6-10]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `memoir`,

```
\marginpar{
\begin{tcolorbox[colframe=Red,colback=Gray!25,boxrule=3bp,arc=12bp,title=\textbf{Title}]
Content
\end{tcolorbox}
}
```

seems to work. So, it's not as you ask, rather this is a way to have:
`tcolorbox` to work inside a `marginpar` environment
but that may not be exactly what you need

Comment: You are answering the question, can we get tcolobox to work inside a marginpar, which is not only not exactly mine but actually a completely different one!

Comment: Apologies...it was kinda dawning on me as I wrote the [first] non-answer.  For another non-answer, but potentially more adjacent to your question, with negative values for marginparsep, I was able to get a sidepar (not marginpar) inside the tcolorbox.